# "Uncaught TypeError: window.HTMLOUT.showHTML is not a function"

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-webview

I am trying to inject JavaScript for reading on specific value while loading `webView`.

These are the properties i used for my `webView`.

```
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.clearHistory();
    webView.clearCache(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
```

and i am injecting javacript in my `onPageFInished()` method.

```
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, final String url) {
            webView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value+'</head>');");   
                }
            });
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
```

Below code is `MyJavaScriptInterface`.

```
public  class MyJavaScriptInterface{

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html_data) {
        if(html_data.contains("response_code")){
            Log.e(TAG, " ======>  HTML Data : "+  html_data);
            new MakeQueryPayment().execute();
        }        
    }
}
```

Error i captured from the Logcat.

```
01-08 17:56:43.701 I/chromium(27026): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: window.HTMLOUT.showHTML is not a function", source:  (1)
```

I m facing this problem only in **Samsung Galaxy Tab A**, Model Number is **SM-T550** , Android Version is **5.0.2**. In other devices which we have it's working fine. Can any one please help me out from this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change minifyEnabled to false in build.gradle.

Comment: thanks tiny sunlight , your answer fix my problem, however there must be other way around since having minifyEnabled is very important.

Comment: check if minifyEnabled is set to true for your app.
reffer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/35093618/2615223

Answer (score 4):

I try on Galaxy Tab 4, this code running well on this device.

> WebView properties

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webView);
webView.clearHistory();
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(2);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
webView.loadUrl("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34746626/uncaught-typeerror-window-htmlout-showhtml-is-not-a-function");

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
    }              

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                    Bitmap favicon) {
    }

    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.showHTML('<html>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</html>');");
    }
});
```

> JavaScript Interface

```
public  class MyJavaScriptInterface{

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showHTML(String html_data) {
        Log.e("", " ======>  HTML Data : "+  html_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: At my place also it's working fine in other samsung tabs.

Comment: @nurisezgin i tried to send the value of html_data to UI but i got empty data on textarea using mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:MyFunction('" + html_data + "');"); the toast shows the value but i can't pass it to javascript! could you help me fix it?Thanks

Comment: Hi! What is your problem exactly, do you try to call javascript method from java?

Answer (score 1):

For me, as it was working fine before upgrading to the latest targetSDK, I just had to add the annotation `@JavascriptInterface` on all my functions.

Example:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public void eventDragStart() {
    // do somthing
}
```

Comment: that is the actual solution. because android studio cannot get funtion name from string so mark them!